# Ag-grid will not render in JHipster app (Angular 7 + Webpack 4)

Tags: jhipster, ag-grid, angular7, webpack-4, ag-grid-angular

I have thoroughly followed the instructions in the following guides:

[Get Started with ag-Grid in Your Angular Project](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-getting-started/?utm_source=ag-grid-readme&utm_medium=repository&utm_campaign=github)

[Angular Webpack 3](https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-angular-webpack-3/)

My `app.module.ts` includes:

```
import { AgGridModule } from 'ag-grid-angular';
...
@NgModule({
    imports: [
         ...,
         AgGridModule.withComponents([])
    ]
})
```

In `vendor.css`

```
@import "~ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css";
@import "~ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css";
```

In the `home.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {GridOptions} from 'ag-grid-community';

@Component({
    selector: 'jhi-home',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['home.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {    
    private gridOptions: GridOptions;
    public rowData: any[];
    private columnDefs: any[];

    constructor(
        private accountService: AccountService,
        private loginModalService: LoginModalService,
        private eventManager: JhiEventManager
    ) {
        this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{
            onGridReady: () => {
                this.gridOptions.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
            }
        };
        this.columnDefs = [
            {headerName: 'Make', field: 'make'},
            {headerName: 'Model', field: 'model'},
            {headerName: 'Price', field: 'price'}
        ];
        this.rowData = [
            {make: 'Toyota', model: 'Celica', price: 35000},
            {make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000},
            {make: 'Porsche', model: 'Boxter', price: 72000}
        ];
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }
}
```

Eventually in the template I added the component:

```
<ag-grid-angular #agGrid style="width: 500px; height: 300px;"
         [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
         [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
         [rowData]="rowData">
</ag-grid-angular>
```

Although there are no errors at build, the grid will not render. That is the way my HTML looks after compilation:

[image]

I presume there may be an incompatibility between Angular 7/Webpack 4/the way Jhipster loads the app and ag-grid-angular.

Would you suggest any solution? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should import the AgGridModule on each one of your 'entities' apps modules, not on your main apps.module.ts.